# how do to get an image from one viewController to the next like a global

Tags: xcode, swift

I have just a camera on my `CameraController`. I want the picture from my `CameraContoller` to go to my `ComposeViewController` inside of the `image` View in the `ComposeViewController`. so basically I need it so the the picture taken transfers to the other view controller once taken. There are 2 separate view controllers below in the code.

Code:

```
  import UIKit
  import AVFoundation

   class CameraController : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080

    var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    var error : NSError?
    var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera, error: &error)

    if (error == nil && captureSession?.canAddInput(input) != nil){

        captureSession?.addInput(input)

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) != nil){
            captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            captureSession?.startRunning()

        }

    }

}
@IBOutlet var tempImageView: UIImageView!

   func didPressTakePhoto(){

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            (sampleBuffer, error) in

            if sampleBuffer != nil {

                var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                var dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                var cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

                var image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                self.tempImageView.image = image
                self.tempImageView.hidden = false

            }                            
        })
    }             
}

var didTakePhoto = Bool()

func didPressTakeAnother(){
    if didTakePhoto == true{
        tempImageView.hidden = true
        didTakePhoto = false            
    }
    else{
        captureSession?.startRunning()
        didTakePhoto = true
        didPressTakePhoto()            
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    didPressTakeAnother()
}

  }

   //-----Below is my Next View Controller where i want the image from      the above view controller to show up---------------------------------------      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------  --------------

       class ComposeViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var captionTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var previewImage: UIImageView!

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "GotoProfile")
    swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    tap.addTarget(self, action: "GoBack")
    view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    captionTextView.delegate = self 

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
func CaptonField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if range.length + range.location > count(captionTextView.text){

        return false

    }

    let NewLength = count(captionTextView.text) + count(string) - range.length
    return NewLength <= 35
}


@IBAction func chooseImageFromCamera() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(picker,animated: true, completion:nil)

}    

func GotoProfile(){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("NewCameraViewFromComposeSegue", sender: nil)

}
func GoBack(){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoBackFromCamerasegue", sender: nil)

}


@IBAction func addImageTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.PhotoLibrary)!
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

        self.previewImage.image = image

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
func textViewShouldEndEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    captionTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}

@IBAction func composeTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let date = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    let localDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    let imageToBeUploaded = self.previewImage.image
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToBeUploaded)


    let file: PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData)
    let fileCaption: String = self.captionTextView.text

    var photoToUpload = PFObject(className: "Posts")
    photoToUpload["Image"] = file
    photoToUpload["Caption"] = fileCaption
    photoToUpload["addedBy"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
    photoToUpload["date"] = localDate

    photoToUpload.save()

    println("Successfully Posted.")

    let vc: AnyObject? = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavigationController")
    self.presentViewController(vc as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)       

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a segue to get from the first to the second ViewController ?

If so you can access the second VC in in your first VC in the prepareForSegue function :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ComposeVCIdentifier" {            
        let composeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ComposeViewController
        composeViewController.someVariable = myPicture
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this give me the same image on booth view controllers for instance. Making my stillimageOutput the same picture as my previewimage on my composeView controller?

Comment: And where it say my picture in your comment am is opposed to change that to the unique variable for my picture I'm trying to send or is that the actual code thanks?

Comment: to comment 1) yes, comment 2) I don't understand your question

Comment: Ok thanks for getting this far but can you make a regular function not a override function so I can see how to do this with just a regular func? Thanks

Comment: You have to ViewControllers, so you're probable using a segue to move from the first to the second. If so you can use 'prepareForSegue', but since this is already defined you must override it. If you're not using a segue and you have a var containing the second VC, you can set the variable in the method where you load the second VC. I suggest reading the storyboard tutorials at : http://www.raywenderlich.com/category/ios